# SWT DirectoryDialog not showing Android Smartphone

Tags: java, swt

I've written an application to administer my audio files using Java/SWT. Now I want to copy files from the PC to my mobile Phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy A30, Android 10 device. When I hook up the phone to the PC (Win 10) it is listed in Explorer under "This PC" as "Galaxy A30s" and I can scroll through folders and files just fine. However when I open the SWT DirectoryDialog the phone is not listed there.
Has anybody a tip why this is and how to solve it?
Many thanks.

Here is the calling code snippet:

```
AudioFilesCopy afc = new AudioFilesCopy(shell);
        if (afc.selectDirectory() != null) {
            Cursor waitCursor = shell.getDisplay().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_WAIT);
            shell.setCursor(waitCursor);
            afc.copyFiles(plSongs);
            shell.setCursor(null);
        }
```

This is the class:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class AudioFilesCopy {
    
    private Shell shell;
    private Logger logger;
    private String selDirectory;
    
    public AudioFilesCopy(Shell parent) {
        
        logger =  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
        logger.addHandler(MusicCatalog.fileHandler);

        shell = new Shell(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.Close | SWT.MAX | SWT.MIN | SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    }

    public String selectDirectory() {
        
        DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
        dialog.setFilterPath(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\TransferOrdner");
        selDirectory = dialog.open();
        return selDirectory;
    }
 
    public void copyFiles(String[] plSongs) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < plSongs.length; i++) {
            Path source = Paths.get(plSongs[i]);
            Path target = Paths.get(selDirectory, source.getFileName().toString());
//          System.out.println("Copy " + source + " to " + target);
            try {
                Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FileDialog instead of DirectoryDialog.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Verified working on my system. Kindly share code for further assistance.

Comment: did it work, friend? if it didn't, what did you do to solve it? maybe i can learn from you as well.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work and I don't know where to find a solution. What I "learned" from investigating the net, is that Anfdroid 10 is hooked up to Win 10 by using the Media Transfer Protocol which neither FileDialog nor DirectoryDialog support. So I was looking for a way to use my Android 10 device like a USB mass storage, but I did not find a way. So I thought I'd ask for help here... may be there are Java Classes which can handle MTP? In the interim I copy the files to a folder on the PC and use the file explorer to copy them from there to the phone.

Comment: Hello, sorry again for the late reply. Just in case you have not found a solution yet, I am having no issue viewing MTP devices using SWT FileDialog. ```FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(shell);``` and then ```fileDialog.open();```. Make sure this opening is done from the main class that hosts the root shell.

Comment: If all else fails, we could use the JNI to 'hook' the os and intercept calls from OS modules that deal with MTP connection; but personally I would'nt go down that road of boilderplate/ overwork nightmare. For me, I'm on Android 11 so perhaps that is why it is working. Ultimately it'll be better to upgrade to the new version. But if the project is necessary you might really want to look into OS hooking concepts.